# Create a process that runs in background using python

Tags: python, process

I want to write a python program that runs in the background.
I mean, like we install Python package. And later, we can run any script using python in front of the script name. This means that some python process is running in background which can take inputs and perform actions.

And in case of linux, you can call grep from anywhere. That means grep is also running in the background somehow.

I want to write something like that in python. When I call certain function with name and arguments at any time, it should perform the intended action without caring for the original code. But I am not able to find how to achieve that.

Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the fact that you can call `grep` does not mean that  grep is also running in the background. In fact it just means that it's on your `PATH` and that it's executable. In your case, you want to look into [`console_scripts`, which are `setuptools` `entrypoints`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarification: the fact that you can run `python` or `grep` in a console just by typing their name, does not mean that they *run in background*. It means that there exist an **executable** file in some location, and this location is listed in the environment variable `PATH`.

For example, on my system I can run Python by typing `python`. The python executable is installed at `/usr/local/bin/python`, and has the execute permission bit on.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

and yes, `/usr/local/bin` is contained in `PATH`.

You can do the same with python scripts:

- ensure that the very first line of your script contains `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- give your script execute permissions: `chmod a+x yourScript`
- either move your script to one of the directories contained in `$PATH`, or add the directory where your script is located to `PATH`: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/you/scripts`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

you can roll out your own daemon by inheriting the Daemon class and overriding run method

```
from daemon import Daemon
class run_daemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        import sys
        run_daemon.execute_shell_command(sys.argv[1])

    @staticmethod
    def execute_shell_command(ShellCommand):
        import subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(ShellCommand, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.communicate()
```